# Having a weird bug in my Google App Script. It keeps deleting info?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18IM3sYkvpcCgjUBizCw5AKu4S5GPyKQF8lodcnBLwps/edit?usp=sharing

Feel free to take a look. Basically, this is an entry form to help enter player stats for a football game. You enter the stats in the "Input" tab, and the script writes it in the "New Player Stats" tab. The trouble I'm having is when you enter in a WR or a TE, the script deletes the previous player's stats in the "New Player Stats" table then enters in the next player. It works fine for the other positions, but WR and TE just disappear.

Any help would be gratefully appreciated!

Comment: Found your typo/error: You're pasting multiple lines there. Look at google script line 90 `var wrInput = playerInput.getRange('H22:L30');` Should be `var wrInput = playerInput.getRange('H22:L22');`

Comment: ps. I messed a bit around with some formatting on the google sheet (mostly un hiding some of the rows/columns. So you need to go back and fix those, but thats how i discovered the issue

Comment: Not sure if this was solved by @chitown88 comment, but if not, can you provide more details about your issue, including a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: @lambichus, the reproducible example (data and code) is all found with the google sheet link they provided. I tested it with the fix to the typo and it does work/solve the issue they were having.

Comment: @chitown88 A 140-lines long code without any indication on where the error is happening is not a _minimal_ reproducible example.

Comment: he provided everything needed to debug with very minimal effort on the other end (literally 2 clicks of the mouse to reproduce the issue). I guess he could have pasted the code into the post, but again, it's there in the link. There is/was no raised error in the code so there will be no way for him to indicate at what line the unexpected results were occurring, which is what he points out (works fine for the other positions, but WR and TE just disappear.) He was asking why that was occurring. It was a simple typo in the code that was producing the unexpected results.